# Upload video to S3 with React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, amazon-s3, video

I am trying to include a video upload functionality in my react-native app. I have gone through the many tutorials and questions on here about the issue but I think the problem I'm having is different than what I've seen. The videos are being recorded and saved using a native component I created. I'm developing for android at the moment, and I'm saving the videos using a MediaRecorder object, and then the component sends the filepath back to react native code for storage. this seems to work fine for playing videos in react-native but I also want to upload the videos to s3 and be able to watch the video on the AWS console. When i go to play the videos in the AWS Console i get an error "No video with supported format and mimetype found." Which leads me to believe that when the files are being uploaded, there's an encoding issue. Here is the code snippet that i believe got me closest to success

```
  const s3 = new AWS.S3()

  const uploadFileToS3 = (dat) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: keyName,
      Body: dat,
      ContentType: 'video/mp4', 
    }

    return s3.upload(params).promise();
  }

  try{
    console.log("Here! " + filename)
    const file = await RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(filename);

    console.log("Starting upload! ")
    await uploadFileToS3(file);
    console.log("Finished upload! ")
      
  } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
  }
```

Ive tried using PutObjectCommand and S3Client from "@aws-sdk/client-s3", Ive tried multipart uploads, and aws' amplify library. All of which i would ultimately get stuck at "No video with supported format and mimetype found." I also tried RNS3 from 'react-native-aws3' and that could not correctly read the filepath that i had stored from the android component.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please visit this blog for more understanding.

https://www.mohammadfaisal.dev/blog/how-to-upload-files-to-aws-s3-in-react

2. Here are some useful discussions and solutions.

[How to upload video files into an S3 bucket using React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135778/how-to-upload-video-files-into-an-s3-bucket-using-react)

3. I achieved and provided the solution with the help of this.

https://aboutreact.com/react-native-upload-file-to-aws-s3-bucket/

4. this is how i modified ur question with my response

   ```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const RNFetchBlob = require('rn-fetch-blob');  

    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
      const uploadFileToS3 = async (filename, bucket, keyName) => {
      try {
        console.log("Here! " + filename);

        // Read the file as a buffer
        const file = await RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(filename, 'base64');

        console.log("Starting upload! ");

        const params = {
          Bucket: bucket,
          Key: keyName,
          Body: Buffer.from(file, 'base64'), // Convert base64 to Buffer
          // ContentType: 'video/mp4', // Try without specifying ContentType
        };

        await s3.upload(params).promise();

        console.log("Finished upload! ");
      } 
      catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };
    // Example usage
    uploadFileToS3('path/to/your/video.mp4', 'your-s3-bucket-name', 'your-s3-key-name');
   ```

Comment: Yes the blog article and solution was very helpful! I wasn't understanding how to create a buffer from the file in react-native but your solution works for me! Thank you!!

Comment: I hope that works, @RyanLaw, but you didn't accept the answer I provided.